# ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload automatically upload

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I use `ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload`. It works when the user clicked in the start upload button. I want to change it so when the file is selected or drag-and-dropped, the uploader starts uploading automatically. What should I do? my  code  is:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" />

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUploader"  OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUploader_UploadComplete" runat="server"  />

protected void AjaxFileUploader_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    AjaxFileUploader.SaveAs(MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/" + e.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your Upload component to use the class "FileAttachmentUpload"
then use the below jQuery.

```
$(".FileAttachmentUpload").change(function () {
  $(".FileAttachmentUpload .ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").click();
});

$(".ajax__fileupload_dropzone").on('drop', function () {
  $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").click();
});
```

Comment: thank's for your replay.this code is work correctly,but when i drag and darop image this not work and should click in update button

Comment: other file ok except images?

Comment: i just upload image no other type

Comment: May be you need to use chrome to show out is there any ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton available?